# Animating a sprite with JavaFX on key input

Tags: animation, javafx, sprite, timeline, keyframe

I'm new to JavaFX but have a good understanding of object orientated Java. The following program is a combination of two examples, one that animates and moves shapes , the other animates an object on a mouse button press. Much of the functionality has been removed or changed for my needs.

I've searched through many examples but haven't found one I fully understand regarding moving a sprite and animating on  key press.In my program I'm sure that I'm not using the right classes to create the game object, even though with some tweaking I'm sure it could work.

I added some `println` functions to test the animation. The problem seems to be that the `KeyFrame` part in the `walkSouth` animation isn't working/playing.

My question is:

1. Should I be using different JavaFX classes to create the sprite-sheet animation?
2. Can this code be easily adapted to function so I can get a better understanding of how JavaFX works.

Here is the main class:

```
package testing;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    private enum UserAction{
        NONE,NORTH,SOUTH;
    }
    private static  int APP_W = 200;
    private static  int APP_H = 200;

    private Scene scene;

    private UserAction action = UserAction.NONE;

    private Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    private boolean running = true;
    private int FPS = 60;

    private Parent createContent(){
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(APP_W,APP_H);

        Image cat_image = new Image("file:res/cata.png");
        GameObject obj = new GameObject(cat_image,12,8);
        obj.setTranslateX(100);
        obj.setTranslateY(100);

        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000/FPS), event -> {
            if(!running)
                return;

            switch(action){
                case NORTH:
                    obj.setTranslateY(obj.getTranslateY()-1);
                    break;

                case SOUTH:
                    obj.walkSouth();
                    obj.setTranslateY(obj.getTranslateY()+1);
                    break;
                case NONE:
                    obj.pauseAnimation();
                    break;
            }
        });

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        root.getChildren().add(obj);

        return root;
    }

    private void restartGame(){
        stopGame();
        startGame();
    }
    private void stopGame(){
        running = false;
        timeline.stop();
    }
    private void startGame(){
        timeline.play();
        running = true;
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        scene = new Scene(createContent());

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case W:
                    action = UserAction.NORTH;
                    break;
                case S:
                    action = UserAction.SOUTH;
                    break;
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case W:
                    action = UserAction.NONE;
                    break;
                case S:
                    action = UserAction.NONE;
                    break;
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Simple Animation");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        startGame();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the GameObject class:

```
package testing;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Duration;


/**
 * Created by matt on 26/02/17.
 */
public class GameObject extends Pane {

    ObjectImage objectImage;

    public GameObject( Image image, int columns, int rows){
        objectImage = new ObjectImage(image,columns,rows);
        getChildren().setAll(objectImage);
    }

    public void pauseAnimation(){
        getChildren().setAll(objectImage);
        objectImage.pauseAnimation();
    }

    public void walkSouth(){
        getChildren().setAll(objectImage);
        objectImage.walkSouth();
    }

}

class ObjectImage extends ImageView {

    private Rectangle2D[] clips;
    private double  width,height;
    private Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    public ObjectImage(Image image,int columns,int rows){

        width = image.getWidth()/columns;
        height = image.getHeight()/rows;

        clips = new Rectangle2D[rows*columns];
        int count=0;
        for(int row =0;row < rows;row++ )
            for(int column = 0 ; column < columns; column++,count++)
                clips[count] = new Rectangle2D(width * column, height * row,width,height);

        setImage(image);
        setViewport(clips[0]);

    }

    public void pauseAnimation(){
        timeline.pause();
    }

    public void walkSouth(){
        System.out.println("walk south test");
        IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame( Duration.millis(1000/5), event -> {
            if(count.get() < 2) count.set(count.get()+1);
            else count.set(0);
            setViewport(clips[count.get()]);
            System.out.println("frame test");
        });

        timeline.setCycleCount(timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.getKeyFrames();
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

[This is the sprite-sheet image I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYaws.png)

[This is the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKyuK.png)

Comment: I may not be able to answer your 2 questions now, but I can see that you forgot to add the frame in your timeline in the walkSouth method, and that's why the animation is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by the comment, you did forget to add the frame in the walkSouth method. (Also you set each picture frame in walkSouth method to 200ms. Did you meant to change that?) Here's the code after changing:

```
public void walkSouth(){
    System.out.println("walk south test");
    IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame( Duration.millis(1000/FPS), event -> {
        if(count.get() < 2) count.set(count.get()+1);
        else count.set(0);
        setViewport(clips[count.get()]);
    });

    timeline.setCycleCount(timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(frame); //This was the offending line.
    timeline.play();
}
```

To answer your first question, yes there are many other options of classes you could use. Two options you could do is use the `AnimationTimer` or the `Transition` class. Here's a brief explanation for both (with code samples).

`AnimationTimer` is called every cycle or frame of rendering, which I believe you might be wanting this one:

```
public void walkSouth(){
    System.out.println("walk south test");
    IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    AnimationTimer tmr = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long nanoTime)
        {
            //nanoTime specifies the current time at the beginning of the frame in nano seconds.
            if(count.get() < 2) count.set(count.get()+1);
            else count.set(0);
            setViewport(clips[count.get()]);
        }

    };
    tmr.start();
    //call tmr.stop() to stop/ pause timer.
}
```

If however, you don't want an animation to be called each frame, you could extend `Transition`. A transition has an `frac` (fractional) value ranging from 0 to 1 that increases with respect to time. I'm not going to go into a whole lot detail, but I'm sure you could look up some more information on the [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html#interpolate-double-).

```
public void walkSouth(){
    System.out.println("walk south test");
    IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    Transition trans = new Transition() {
        {
            setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(1000 / 60.0));
        }
        @Override
        public void interpolate(double frac)
        {
            if (frac != 1) 
                return;
            //End of one cycle.
            if(count.get() < 2) count.set(count.get()+1);
            else count.set(0);
            setViewport(clips[count.get()]);
        }

    };
    trans.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    trans.playFromStart();
    //Use trans.pause to pause, trans.stop to stop.
}
```

Comment: Great , thank you I have it working now and will definitely try to convert it to use animation and transition classes.
One thing to note, the `IntegerProperty` within the `walkSouth` method, I should have created and initialised it outside of the method as each time it is called it resets the counting cycle, even when holding the button down.

Comment: you could just try using a regular instance integer variable then